# Problems when the user wants to modify his data / The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django-views

I am new to programming, and I am having a problem with modifying user data.
The user registers, logs in and a profile is created; but when the user wants to access "my profile", modify something and save it, it throws an error and does not make the corresponding update.

I think this is where the code breaks down. It does not consider the form as valid
views.py

**view.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from users.forms import Edit_profile_form

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from users.models import User_profile
from users.forms import User_registration_form



   
  @login_required
def my_profile(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:                                                     
        try:            
            user = User_profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except:            
            user = User_profile.objects.create(user=request.user)
        user.save()     
    if request.method == "POST":            
            form = Edit_profile_form(request.POST, request.FILES)               
            if form.is_valid():                                                       
                user.name = form.cleaned_data['name']                           
                user.last_name = form.cleaned_data ['last_name']
                user.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
                user.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                user.website = form.cleaned_data['website']
                user.save()                
                return redirect('inicio')
            
    elif request.method == "GET":            
            form = Edit_profile_form(initial = {
                                    'name':user.name,
                                    'last_name':user.last_name,
                                    'description':user.description,
                                    'image': user.image,
                                    'website':user.website,
                                    })
            context = {'form':form,'user':user}    
            return render(request, 'users/my_profile.html', context=context)



 def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = User_registration_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:            
            context = {'errors':form.errors}
            form = User_registration_form()
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)  

    elif request.method == 'GET':        
        form = User_registration_form()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form}) 

def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None: 
                print('login request estoy aca 002')       
                login(request, user)    
                
                context = {'message':f'Bienvenido {username}!! :D'}         
                return render(request, 'inicio.html', context = context)    

        form = AuthenticationForm()     
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'error': 'Formulário inválido', 'form': form})

    elif request.method == 'GET':        
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from users.views import login_request, register,my_profile                          
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login_request, name='login'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name = 'users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path ('profile/', my_profile, name='my_profile'),
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class User_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='Nombre')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='Apellido',default='')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, verbose_name='Descripción')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image/', blank=True, verbose_name='Imagen')
    website = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' - profile'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


from django import forms

class User_registration_form(UserCreationForm): 
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)  
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

   

class Edit_profile_form(forms.Form):
    
    name = forms.CharField (required=False, label='Nombre', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ingresa tu Nombre'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Apellido', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ingresa tu Apellido'}))
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Descripción', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholde': 'Contanos algo de vos'}))
    image = forms.ImageField()
    website = forms.CharField(required=False, label='WebSite', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ingresa tu website'}))
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User_profile

@admin.register(User_profile)
class User_profileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','last_name', 'email', 'description', 'image', 'website']
```

**html my_profile**

```
{% extends "padre.html" %}

{% block bloqueQueCambia %}

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <table>
    
        <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
            {% if user.image %}
            <img src="{{user.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" style="width: 18rem;" alt="Card image cap">
            {% else %}
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png" style="width: 18rem;"alt="Card image cap">
            {% endif %} 
            {{form.as_table}}
            <div class="card-body">
            <p></p> 
            <a href="/users/delete_user/?={{user.user}}" class="card-link">Borrar</a>
            </div>
       </div>
    
    
    </table>
    
    <p></p><input type="submit" name="enviar"></p>    
    
</form>
    
{% endblock %}
```

I leave attached two images.

One is of the VS terminal when the user enters his profile, modifies it and wants to save that change (when it breaks).
And the other one is the error that shows me on the screen.

[Error displayed on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDMeX.png)

[Errors displayed by console VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0u0d.png)

I hope the post can be read correctly, it is the first time I make one.
The code is not for real application, it is to be presented in a course.

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: What should happen if `request.method == "POST"` but the form is not valid (i.e. `form.is_valid()` returns `False`? In this case your `my_profile` method will return `None`, hence the error message in your title. You'll need to handle this case: users will often enter invalid data in forms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. This is way more code than should be necessary to explain the problem.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: The error displayed on the page is:

ValueError at /users/profile/
The view users.views.my_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profile/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
The view users.views.my_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forget one return in your view:

```
def my_profile(request):    
    ... # some staff
    
    if request.method == "POST":
            ... # some staff
            if form.is_valid():
                ... # some staff
                print('my profile estoy aca 005')
                return redirect('inicio')
            else:
                print('la sentencia else se ejecutara')
                # WHERE is RETURN something?
```

I think it should be:

```
    else:
        print('la sentencia else se ejecutara')
        context = {'form':form,'user':user}    
        return render(request, 'users/my_profile.html', context=context)
```

Comment: I put that "else" just to see if it would go through. Actually, In the original code it is not.
That's the return you say I'm missing, the "else" return?

I modified the code in the publication without the else, and the print

Comment: Sorry if that "else" was confusing, I thought it was understood that it was just for testing purposes.